# Retain value in textbox after ajax success

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a select box, that contains option X and O. I put a function Onchange on it to populate the value in the textbox.

```
<input type="text" id="remarks1"/>
```

this is my script for select box to populate value in textbox :

```
$(document).on('click', '#1', function() { ////---make td transform to dropdown list box when click---///
      if($(this).find('select').length == 0) {
          $(this).empty();  //clears out current text in the table
          $(this).append('<select onchange="myFunction()" id="Remarks" name="Remarks"><option value=""></option><option <?php if ($Remarks=='X') echo 'selected';?> value="X" style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;">X<option style="font-size:20px;color:green;font-weight:bold;" <?php if ($Remarks=='O') echo 'selected';?> value="O">O</select>');
      }
});



function myFunction(){
        var dropdown1= document.getElementById("Remarks"); ////===== select box
        var selection1 = dropdown1.value;
        //console.log(selection1);
        var emailTextBox1 = document.getElementById("remarks1"); //==== textbox
        emailTextBox1.value = selection1;
     }
```

then this is my ajax when button save is click :

```
 $(document).on('click','#btnSave',function(){
            var employeeName = document.getElementById('employeeName').value;
            var r1 = document.getElementById('remarks1').value;
            var r2 = document.getElementById('remarks2').value;

            $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'update_data.php',
                    data: {
                        'DAY1' :r1,
                        'DAY1_A' :r2,
                        'employeeName' :employeeName

                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#content").html(data)
                        $(".loader").fadeOut("very slow");              
                        $("#content").hide().fadeIn(500)

                        alert("Changes Succesfully Saved!");


                    },
                    error:function(data){
                        alert('Failed');
                    }
                })  

    });
```

how can I retain now the value of textbox after ajax success?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [*localStorage*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the value so that you use that later:

```
function myFunction(){
    var dropdown1= document.getElementById("Remarks"); ////===== select box
    var selection1 = dropdown1.value;
    localStorage.setItem('remarks', selection1); // set the value in localStorage
    var emailTextBox1 = document.getElementById("remarks1"); //==== textbox
    emailTextBox1.value = selection1;
 }
```

Then in the AJAX *success*:

```
success: function(data){
           $("#content").html(data)
           $(".loader").fadeOut("very slow");              
           $("#content").hide().fadeIn(500)
           var remarks = localStorage.getItem('remarks'); // get from localStorage
           document.getElementById("remarks1").value = remarks; // set the value in the text box;
           alert("Changes Succesfully Saved!");
        }
```

Comment: i don't know but it doesn't work for me. Textbox still has no value when page reloads.

Comment: @Gelxxxx, there might be some other issue as logically it should work. Try to see the *localStorage* value in *console*....

Comment: yes remarks1 have a value in localstorage in console. but it should be display in the textbox right? but it doesn't show its value.

Comment: @Gelxxxx, you can debug the value in ajax success. I guess the textbox value is resetting some where after the success.....

Comment: yeah I guess also textbox is resetting it's value, but i can't figure it out where it is.

Comment: @Gelxxxx, you have to debug your code step by step to identify that:)

Comment: I think there is some issue in way of coding in function myFunction() that makes value in textbox resets.

Comment: $(window).on('unload', function(){
   saveSettings();
   loadSettings();
});

function loadSettings() {
  $('#remarks1').val(localStorage.remarks1);
}
function saveSettings() {
 localStorage.remarks1 = $('#remarks1').val();
}          may be this is the problem because i have this on my script...